# Task on the number of iterations

Tags: c++, algorithm

There is a number N
every iteration it becomes equal to (N*2)-1
I need to find out how many steps the number will be a multiple of the original N;

( 1≤ N ≤ 2 · 10 9 )

For example:

```
N = 7; count = 0

N_ = 7*2-1 = 13; count = 1; N_ % N != 0

N_ = 13*2-1 = 25; count = 2; N_ % N != 0

N_ = 25*2-1 = 49; count = 3; N_ % N == 0
```

Answer is 3

if it is impossible to decompose in this way, then output -1

```
       #include <iostream> 
       using namespace std;

       int main(){
           int N,M,c;
           cin >> N;
           if (N%2==0) {
               cout << -1;
               return 0;
           }
           M = N*2-1;
           c = 1;
           while (M%N!=0){
               c+=1;
               M=M*2-1;
           }
           cout << c;
           return 0;
       }
```

It does not fit during (1 second limit). How to optimize the algorithm?

P.S All the answers indicated are optimized, but they don’t fit in 1 second, because you need to change the algorithm in principle. The solution was to use Euler's theorem.

Comment: What do you mean by `It does not fit during (1 second limit)`? What is your actual question

Comment: @Iniad how to optimize the algorithm

Comment: You're going to overflow after about 31 times through the loop.

Comment: This looks optimal enough, what constraints and input you fed to claim that your algorithm does not meet the time constraints

Comment: Time limit: 1 second
Memory Limit: 64 MB

Comment: tester result:AAAAAAATTTTTTTATTTAATTTTTTTATTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT

Comment: A = ACCEPTED  T - TIME LIMIT

Comment: What is the range of input you can get? (i.e upper bound for N?)

Comment: ( 1≤ N ≤ 2 · 10 9 ).

Comment: 2 · 10 to the power of 9? That's 2,000,000,000. Very close to the maximum value of a 32 bit signed integer.  `M = N*2-1;`  will immediately overflow and fill `M` with garbage. Consider using an unsigned integer of at least 32 bits.

Comment: The problem seems ill-posed (or incorrectly reproduced), because there is no upper limit on the values of N during the computation, and the condition "if it is impossible to decompose" might be impossible to establish.

Comment: @YvesDaoust All odd numbers will have a solution. No even number will have a solution.

Comment: @4386427: so trying to find out by program will indeed fail.

Answer (score 5):

The problem, as other answers have suggested, is equivalent to finding `c` such that `pow(2, c) = 1 mod N`. This is impossible if N is even, and possible otherwise (as your code suggests you know).

A linear-time approach is:

```
int c = 1;
uint64_t m = 2;
while (m != 1){
  c += 1;
  m = (2*m)%N;
}
printf("%d\n", c);
```

To solve this in 1 second, I don't think you can use a linear-time algorithm. The worst cases will be when `N` is prime and large. For example 1999999817 for which the above code runs in around 10 seconds on my laptop.

Instead, factor `N` into its prime factors. Solve `2^c = 1 mod p^k` for each prime factor (where p^k appears in the prime factorization of N. Then combine the results using the Chinese Remainder theorem.

When finding the `c` for a given prime power, if `k=1`, the solution is `c=p-1`. When `k` is larger, the details are quite messy, but you can find a written solution here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1863037/discrete-logarithm-modulo-powers-of-a-small-prime

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're overflowing, the int data type only has 32 bits, and overflows 2^31-1 , in this problem you don't need to keep the actual value of M, you can just keep the modulo of n.

```
 while (M%N!=0){
           c+=1;
           M=M*2-1;
           M%=N
       }
```

Edit:In addition, you don't actually need more than N iterations to check if a 0 mod exists, as there are only N different mods to N and it just keeps cycling. so you also need to keep that in mind in case there is no 0 mod.

Comment: if there was an overflow, then the tests would not have the wrong answers, but I have an error associated with time

Comment: This is of course a good step from you, but it does not add speed

Comment: @yoloy how do you know the judge did not give up before it received the wrong answer? This may or may not be the whole problem, but it is a bug.

Comment: Side note: With the `M%=N`, the `M%N` in the loop condition is rendered mostly redundant.

Comment: the while loop will not end when you overflow as the mod will not hit 0, the number will become negative and keep overflowing, which results in time limit exceeded

Comment: in any case, starting the code with this amendment does not change anything (for online tester)

Comment: @yoloy , a recommendation: When you have the bugs all knocked out, ask for help improving the performance over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking). The community there specializes in taking working code and making it better. I linked to the How to Ask pages of their help because you'll want to read it and compose a question that conforms to their requirements before asking.

Comment: This is a good solution for the functional part. However, it **will not work** unless the variables are changed to unsigned int instead of signed int. The best type to use is `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no doubt that the main problem with your code is **signed integer overflow**

I added a print of `M` whenever `M` was changed (i.e. `cout << M << endl;`) and gave it the input 29. This is what I got:

```
57
113
225
449
897
1793
3585
7169
14337
28673
57345
114689
229377
458753
917505
1835009
3670017
7340033
14680065
29360129
58720257
117440513
234881025
469762049
939524097
1879048193
-536870911
-1073741823
-2147483647
1
1
1
1
... endless loop
```

As you see you have signed integer overflow. That is **undefined behavior** in C so anything may happen!! On my machine I ended up with a nasty endless loop. That must be fixed before considering performance.

The simple fix is to add a line like

```
M = M % N;
```

whenever `M` is changed. See the answer from @Malek

Besides that you shall also use an **unsigned** integer, i.e. use `uint32_t` for all variables.

However, that will **not** improve performance.

If you still have performance issue after the above fix, you can try this instead:

```
  uint32_t N;
  cin >> N;
  if (N%2==0) {
    cout << -1;
    return 0;
  }

  // Alternative algorithm
  uint32_t R,c;
  R = 1;
  c = 1;
  while (R != N){
    R = 2*R + 1;
    if (R > N) R = R - N;
    ++c;
  }
  cout << c;
```

On my laptop this algorithm is 2.5 times faster when testing on all odd numbers in the range 1..100000. However, it might not be sufficient for all numbers in the range 1..2*10^9.

Also notice the use of `uint32_t` to avoid integer overflow.